# AngularJS pass value to query API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

What I have are ID values that I want to append to a URL to query the correct object in an API

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-init="tileID = '38'"></div>
```

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('appCtrl',['$scope', '$http', 'ImageTiles', function($scope, $http, ImageTiles){

$scope.$watch('tileID', function(){
  console.log($scope.tileID);
  $scope.get = function(tileID){
    ImageTiles.get({id: tileID}, function(data){
    })
  }
});
}]);
```

**Factory**

```
app.factory('ImageTiles', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('http://api/v1/tiles/:id', {
  id: "@id"
},
{
'query': {
  method: 'GET',
  isArray: false
}
});
}]);
```

Example:

In the HTML I have a value of 38 that's always manually entered in. Would then like to take that value (38) and create the URL of `http://api/v1/tiles/38` to bring back the data of the object that has an ID of 38 on the API.

I can get the ID value but have no idea how to pass it along and make the call to the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's really no need to play with your $resource before consuming it, by wrapping it in that get function, just call it directly:

```
app.controller('appCtrl',['$scope', '$http', 'ImageTiles', function($scope, $http, ImageTiles){

$scope.$watch('tileID', function(){
   console.log($scope.tileID);
   ImageTiles.get({id: $scope.tileID}).$promise.then(function(tile) {
      $scope.tile = tile;
    });


});
}]);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much :). Been a long evening and just couldn't think through how to take that value and pass it through.

Answer (score 0):

It seems only a basic skeleton for the Angular Application.To provide actual routing mechanism you have to modify app.js file for configuring different routes.

please see below sample code  :

```
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when("/Apps", {templateUrl: "partials/App.html", controller: "driversController"}).
    when("/App/:id", {templateUrl: "partials/App.html", controller: "appCtrl"}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/App'});
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it was just a matter of hitting the API with the right URL request and returning the object.

Answer (score 0):

I look like

```
 // Get 
$http.get("http://api/v1/tiles/"+ tileID)
.success(function (response) {
   // Do somthing
});
```

Hope It helps you

Comment: The problem with this is I have to pass along the value into a factory.

Answer (score 0):

In your watch you can specify the arguments newValue and oldValue, and use newValue to call your API.

```
app.controller('appCtrl',['$scope', '$http', 'ImageTiles', function($scope, $http, ImageTiles){

    $scope.$watch('tileID', function(newValue, oldValue){
        console.log(newValue);            
        ImageTiles.get({id: newValue}, function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });

    });
}]);
```